# Converting array of char pointers to lowercase C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I have the following array of char pointers:

```
 char* wordArray[ARRAY_MAX];
```

Now I want to make all the chars lowercase. I have tried to do this by looping through the array then using a pointer to convert every single char to a lowercase using the following code:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 2000; i++) { 
     lineoftext2[i] = lineOfText[i]; //lineoftext is just an array of chars
 }

words = strtok(lineoftext2, "\n ,-.)");
Word wordPlaceArr[ARRAY_MAX];
int wordNumArr[ARRAY_MAX];

while (words != NULL)
{
    wordArray[count] = words;
    count++;
    words = strtok(NULL, "\n ,-.)"); //Remove punctuation an put into an array of char pointers
}

 char* wordpointer;  //HERE is where I want to convert all the letters to lowercase 

for (i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
    for(wordpointer = wordArray[i]; wordpointer != '\0'; wordpointer+= sizeof(char)) {
         *wordpointer = tolower(*wordpointer); //results in seg-fault
    }
}
```

The above code causes a seg-faults when I try to make all the strings in the wordArray lower-case. How can I fix this to convert all the strings to lower-case successefully

Comment: You asked the same question some hours ago already! Do not repost a question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wordpointer != '\0';
```

This will never be true and so the loop will never stop. The pointer will never equal zero unless it wraps around, and you'll crash long before that happens. You meant `*wordpointer != '\0';`.

Comment: This still results in a seg-fault... Nevermind! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do requires that you check whether each character in each string pointed to by `wordArray` `isupper` and then convert the character `tolower`. You were not far off. The following example provides a completion for your approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum { WORD_MAX = 64, ARRAY_MAX = 256 };

int main (void) {

    char *wordArray[ARRAY_MAX] = {NULL};
    char line[WORD_MAX] = "";
    char *p, *delims = " \t\n;,.";
    size_t i, idx = 0;

    while (fgets (line, WORD_MAX, stdin)) { /* read line/tokenize */
        for (p = strtok (line, delims); p; p = strtok (NULL, delims))
            wordArray[idx++] = p;

        if (idx == ARRAY_MAX)   /* check against max */
            break;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) { /* convert to lower and output */
        printf (" wordArray[%2zu] : %-8s => ", i, wordArray[i]);
        p = wordArray[i];
        while (*p) {
            if (isupper (*p))
                *p = tolower (*p);
            p++;
        }
        printf ("%s\n", wordArray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ echo "Joe tOM FRANK haRRY" | ./bin/fgets_ptrarray_tolower
 wordArray[ 0] : Joe      => joe
 wordArray[ 1] : tOM      => tom
 wordArray[ 2] : FRANK    => frank
 wordArray[ 3] : haRRY    => harry
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you want...

It makes use of the fact that `char` in C are actually integers and in ASCII table each lower case character can be respresented as `UPPER_CASE_LETTER+32`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *foo(char *word){
    char *tmp = word; /* For the new string */
    char *ptr = word; /* To save the poiner */

    for(; *ptr; ++ptr, ++tmp) {
        if (*ptr >= 'a' && *ptr <= 'z')
        /* char is lower case */
            *tmp = (*ptr) - 32;
        else if (*ptr >= 'A' && *ptr <= 'Z')
        /* char is upper case */
            *tmp = (*ptr) + 32;
        else
            *tmp = *ptr;
    }
    return word;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char line[]="This is a test LiNe FOR You";
    char *buf;

    printf("%s\n",foo(strtok(line," ")));

    while(buf=strtok(NULL," "))
        printf("%s\n",foo(buf));

    return 0;
}
```

The code could be improved in several aspects such as adding some bounds checking code, or extra checks before calling `strtok()`

Output of the code is

```
$ ./lower_upper.exe
tHIS
IS
A
TEST
lInE
for
yOU
```